# Unique values with frequency count from List<List<String>>

Tags: java, list, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of every element in a `List<List<String>>`, and store the results in a `Map<String,Long>`.

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();    
for(List<String> l : data) {
        for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            String myString = l.get(i);
            long count = data.stream().filter(d -> myString.equals(d)).count();
            map.put(myString, count);
        }
    }
```

My code returns zero as value for every key. Is there a way to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: a String will never be equal to a List<String>. Other hint: Stream has a flatMap method, and Collectors has a toMap() method.

Comment: groupingBy is another (better) option, BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
List<List<String>> listOflists  = new ArrayList<>();
//Initialize your list here
Map<String, Long> map = listOflists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are streaming `data`, which is a `List<List<String>>`. That means that each element of the stream has the type `List<String>`. Then, in the lambda of `filter`, you are trying to see if `myString` (of type `String`) is equal to `d` (of type `List<String>`). This will never be true, making `count` equal to 0 for all elements.

What you need to do is call [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) on the stream returned by `data.stream()`, with the function argument being `List::stream` (or `Collection::stream`). What this done is convert a stream of `List<String>` to a stream of `String`, which you can then call the `filter` method on.